# Subversion workflow for a single developer on a local repository

Tags: svn, version-control

So let's say I am developing a project all by myself with **Subversion**.

How should I organize my things? Should I do everything over the main trunk? Create a branch for each new feature? What?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, how I like to do it is to have a couple of different directories.  Something like this:

**`Trunk`**  (deploy here)

```
   - Production
   - Staging
   - Development/whatever
```

**`Branches`**  (develop here)

```
   - Master Branch (primary)
   - Secondary/Tertiary Branches
```

**`Tags`** (Archive here)

```
    - Name a tag appropriately (timestamp, version, edits)
```

Hope this helps.  Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: If you use Eclipse (or any other IDE), how do you organize things? You have all that in your workspace? Just the trunk? Thanks

Comment: I typically will only have my master_branch or whatever the active dev branch is, active in Eclipse or wherever.  Usually I have the trunks on the server(s) and update there.  I don't ever want code/updates in those, since I only want versions, etc.. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Furthermore, typically how I do it is you merge your master_branch (whatever you're deving in) into your production/staging branches, with versioning/comments, etc..